# Close all popups in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working with JQM and need to close any 'open' popups.

Is there a way to close any currently 'open' popups in JQM?

lee

Answer (score 12):

I found an answer. For anyone else looking to do this, here is the trick:

$('.ui-popup').popup('close');

lee

Comment: +1 u were correct my answer was wrong. This is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer you gave though. It made me realize that all popups have a common class that could be called.

Comment: This only closes my last popup opened :/

Comment: @VaTo using Jquery `each()` function on `'.ui-popup'` selector may do the tricks.